# Code review, help improving this code to avoid duplication

Tags: javascript, function, optimization, sudoku

I working on the Sudoku puzzle, the following code works but it's easy to see that there is a lot of duplicated code. How can I optimize it? Thanks

Problem: `getSection`: This function should accept three arguments: a sudoku grid, and an x and y coordinate for one of the puzzle's 3x3 subgrids. The function should return an array with all the numbers in the specified subgrid.

Input example:

```
var puzzle = [[ 8,9,5,   7,4,2,   1,3,6 ],
             [ 2,7,1,   9,6,3,   4,8,5 ],
             [ 4,6,3,   5,8,1,   7,9,2 ],

             [ 9,3,4,   6,1,7,   2,5,8 ],
             [ 5,1,7,   2,3,8,   9,6,4 ],
             [ 6,8,2,   4,5,9,   3,7,1 ],

             [ 1,5,9,   8,7,4,   6,2,3 ],
             [ 7,4,6,   3,2,5,   8,1,9 ],
             [ 3,2,8,   1,9,6,   5,4,7 ]];
```

Output:

```
getSection(puzzle, 0, 0);
// -> [ 8,9,5,2,7,1,4,6,3 ]
```

Solution:

```
 function getSection(arr, x, y) {
    var section = [];

    if (y === 0) {
        arr = arr.slice(0, 3);
        if (x === 0) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(0, 3));
            })
        } else if (x === 1) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(3, 6));
            })
        } else {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(6, 9));
            })
        }
    }


    if (y === 1) {
        arr = arr.slice(4, 7);
        if (x === 0) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(0, 3));
            })
        } else if (x === 1) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(3, 6));
            })
        } else {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(6, 9));
            })
        }
    }

    if (y === 2) {
        arr = arr.slice(6, 9);
        if (x === 0) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(0, 3));
            })
        } else if (x === 1) {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(element.slice(3, 6));
            })
        } else {
            arr.forEach(function (element) {
                section.push(elemet.slice(6, 9));
            })
        }
    }
    var subgrid = section.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    },
        []
    );
    return subgrid;

}

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 0, 0));
// // -> [ 8,9,5,2,7,1,4,6,3 ]

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 1, 0));
// -> [ 7,4,2,9,6,3,5,8,1 ]
```

Comment: might be better to ask there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although you'll get downvoted to oblivion probably, I enjoyed this - and I hope the answers will be of good use to you

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your answers, it was really helpful and it's very much appreciate it. I know  this question is too basic for all of you but I dont feel bad about it since I'm new at this and I want to improve my practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `x` and `y` will not exceed your array length. Here's the simplest way to achieve the solution.

```
function getSection(arr, x, y) {
  var GRID_SIZE = 3;
  var indexX = x*GRID_SIZE;
  var indexY = y*GRID_SIZE;
  var results = [];
  for(var i = indexY; i< indexY+GRID_SIZE; i++){
    results = results.concat(puzzle[i].slice(indexX, indexX+GRID_SIZE));
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 0, 0));
// // -> [ 8,9,5,2,7,1,4,6,3 ]

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 1, 0));
// -> [ 7,4,2,9,6,3,5,8,1 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take using ES6

```js
const puzzle = [
  [8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 2, 1, 3, 6],
  [2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5],
  [4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 7, 9, 2],

  [9, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 5, 8],
  [5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 6, 4],
  [6, 8, 2, 4, 5, 9, 3, 7, 1],

  [1, 5, 9, 8, 7, 4, 6, 2, 3],
  [7, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9],
  [3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 4, 7]
];

const GRID_SIZE = 3;

function getOffset(coordinate) {
  const start = coordinate * GRID_SIZE;
  const end = start + GRID_SIZE;
  return [start, end];
}


function getSection(arr, x, y) {
  const yOffset = getOffset(y);
  const xOffset = getOffset(x);

  const elements = arr.slice(...yOffset);
  return elements
    .map(element => element.slice(...xOffset))
    .reduce((subgrid, grid) => [...subgrid, ...grid], []);
}

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 0, 0));
// // -> [ 8,9,5,2,7,1,4,6,3 ]

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 1, 0));
// -> [ 7,4,2,9,6,3,5,8,1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as @nutboltu but almost as concise.

```
function getSection(arr, x, y) {
    var section = [];

    z = (y===0?0:y+y+2);
    arr = arr.slice(z, z+3);
    arr.forEach(function (element) {
        section.push(element.slice(z, z+3));
    })
    var subgrid = section.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    },
        []
    );
    return subgrid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional way you could do it:

```js
var puzzle = [
  [8, 9, 5,   7, 4, 2,   1, 3, 6],
  [2, 7, 1,   9, 6, 3,   4, 8, 5],
  [4, 6, 3,   5, 8, 1,   7, 9, 2],

  [9, 3, 4,   6, 1, 7,   2, 5, 8],
  [5, 1, 7,   2, 3, 8,   9, 6, 4],
  [6, 8, 2,   4, 5, 9,   3, 7, 1],

  [1, 5, 9,   8, 7, 4,   6, 2, 3],
  [7, 4, 6,   3, 2, 5,   8, 1, 9],
  [3, 2, 8,   1, 9, 6,   5, 4, 7]
];

function getSection(puzzle, x, y) {
  var x;
  var y;
  var section = [];
  let firstRow = puzzle[0].slice(0, 3);
  let secondRow = puzzle[1].slice(0, 3);
  let thirdRow = puzzle[2].slice(0, 3);
  let firstRow1 = puzzle[0].slice(3, 6);
  let secondRow1 = puzzle[1].slice(3, 6);
  let thirdRow1 = puzzle[2].slice(3, 6);
  let firstRow2 = puzzle[0].slice(6, 9);
  let secondRow2 = puzzle[1].slice(6, 9);
  let thirdRow2 = puzzle[2].slice(6, 9);
  let fourthRow = puzzle[3].slice(0, 3);
  let fifthRow = puzzle[4].slice(0, 3);
  let sixthRow = puzzle[5].slice(0, 3);
  let fourthRow1 = puzzle[3].slice(3, 6);
  let fifthRow1 = puzzle[4].slice(3, 6);
  let sixthRow1 = puzzle[5].slice(3, 6);
  let fourthRow2 = puzzle[3].slice(6, 9);
  let fifthRow2 = puzzle[4].slice(6, 9);
  let sixthRow2 = puzzle[5].slice(6, 9);
  let seventhRow = puzzle[6].slice(0, 3);
  let eigthRow = puzzle[7].slice(0, 3);
  let ninethRow = puzzle[8].slice(0, 3);
  let seventhRow1 = puzzle[6].slice(3, 6);
  let eigthRow1 = puzzle[7].slice(3, 6);
  let ninethRow1 = puzzle[8].slice(3, 6);
  let seventhRow2 = puzzle[6].slice(6, 9);
  let eigthRow2 = puzzle[7].slice(6, 9);
  let ninethRow2 = puzzle[8].slice(6, 9);
  if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
    return firstRow.concat(secondRow, thirdRow)
  } else if (x === 1 && y === 0) {
    return firstRow1.concat(secondRow1, thirdRow1)
  } else if (x === 2 && y === 0) {
    return firstRow2.concat(secondRow2, thirdRow2)
  } else if (x === 0 && y === 1) {
    return fourthRow.concat(fifthRow, sixthRow)
  } else if (x === 1 && y === 1) {
    return fourthRow1.concat(fifthRow1, sixthRow1)
  } else if (x === 2 && y === 1) {
    return fourthRow2.concat(fifthRow2, sixthRow2)
  } else if (x === 0 && y === 2) {
    return seventhRow.concat(eigthRow, ninethRow)
  } else if (x === 1 && y === 2) {
    return seventhRow1.concat(eigthRow1, ninethRow1)
  } else if (x === 2 & y === 2) {
    return seventhRow2.concat(eigthRow2, ninethRow2)
  }
};

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 0, 0));
// -> [ 8,9,5,2,7,1,4,6,3 ]

console.log(getSection(puzzle, 1, 0));
// -> [ 7,4,2,9,6,3,5,8,1 ]
```

Comment: You will need to explain your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in re: to - "getSection: This function should accept three arguments: a sudoku grid, and an x and y coordinate for one of the puzzle's 3x3 subgrids. The function should return an array with all the numbers in the specified subgrid" - you can assign variables to each of the subgrid's respective rows within the puzzle in order to render measurable subsections that reflect the 3x3 subgrids. then by approaching each of the subsections as their own arrays, you can easily execute array methods that will return whether the respective subsection passes the Sodoku's criterion (i.e. 1-9, no repeats)